# Scripting output of a telnet connection

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting, whois

Another whois question, is it possible for me to take the output of a telnet connection to a file.

```
telnet whois.internic.net 43
```

then I

```
=google.com
```

and get a response.

Can I get this to return to a file for processing after the connection closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the `whois` command?

```
whois -h whois.internic.net =google.com > whois.txt
```

Though in this case I get a better answer from

```
whois =google.com > whois.txt
```

---

**Addendum**

Telnet is great for interactive exploration of arbitrary text-based TCP protocols (such as SMTP, WHOIS etc) but it isn't really good for scripting

try `netcat` instead

```
$ echo =google.com | nc whois.internic.net 43 > whois.txt

$ head whois.txt

Whois Server Version 2.0

Domain names in the .com and .net domains can now be registered
with many different competing registrars. Go to http://www.internic.net
for detailed information.

   Server Name: GOOGLE.COM.ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.LOVE.AND.TOLERANCE.THE-WONDERBOLTS.COM
   IP Address: 50.62.130.9
   Registrar: GODADDY.COM, LLC



$ tail whois.txt
use electronic processes that are automated and high-volume to access or
query the Whois database except as reasonably necessary to register
domain names or modify existing registrations. VeriSign reserves the right
to restrict your access to the Whois database in its sole discretion to ensure
operational stability.  VeriSign may restrict or terminate your access to the
Whois database for failure to abide by these terms of use. VeriSign
reserves the right to modify these terms at any time.

The Registry database contains ONLY .COM, .NET, .EDU domains and
Registrars.



$ grep -i status whois.txt
   Status: clientDeleteProhibited
   Status: clientTransferProhibited
   Status: clientUpdateProhibited
   Status: serverDeleteProhibited
   Status: serverTransferProhibited
   Status: serverUpdateProhibited
```

---

I get same output from netcat as I do from script + telnet. netcat is a lot easier

```
$ grep 'Name Server' whois.telnet | dos2unix | tee a
   Name Server: NS1.GOOGLE.COM
   Name Server: NS2.GOOGLE.COM
   Name Server: NS3.GOOGLE.COM
   Name Server: NS4.GOOGLE.COM
$  grep 'Name Server' whois.netcat | tee b
   Name Server: NS1.GOOGLE.COM
   Name Server: NS2.GOOGLE.COM
   Name Server: NS3.GOOGLE.COM
   Name Server: NS4.GOOGLE.COM
$ diff -s a b
Files a and b are identical
```

---

**Other  ideas**

The canonical tool for scripting telnet is `expect`.

The canonical tool for capturing terminal output is `script`.

In this case I think these would not suit your task (but you may disagree)

Comment: because it does not reply with the domain status

Comment: @Kurtis: see Addendum

Comment: [~]$ echo =google.com | nc whois.internic.net 43 > whois.txt
[~]$ cat whois.txt

Whois Server Version 2.0

Domain names in the .com and .net domains can now be registered
with many different competing registrars. Go to http://www.internic.net
for detailed information.
 ~]$
doesnt seem to work

Comment: @Kurtis: what output were you expecting? nc and telnet return identical output for me.

Comment: I used a different whois server. and got the result I was expecting :D